# Get all general data, and retrieves privacy data (applies if the column that has the value matches the desired parameter) In MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

| ID | NPK | Satker | Privasi |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 211017 | 111111 | Rahasia |
| 2 | 211017 | 111111 | Umum |
| 3 | 216038 | 555555 | Rahasia |
| 4 | 218024 | 333333 | Umum |
| 5 | 204031 | 666666 | Rahasia |
| 6 | 204031 | 666666 | Umum |

**I want to get some data under the following conditions :**

1. npk = 211017 (In this case priority)
2. Satker In ('111111','666666')
3. Privasi In ('Umum') , but if NPK = Input (filter) then all privacy will be taken (Rahasia, and Umum)

**Then the display I want is like this :**

| ID | NPK | Satker | Privasi |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 211017 | 111111 | Rahasia |
| 2 | 211017 | 111111 | Umum |
| 6 | 204031 | 666666 | Umum |

I confuse how to get all privacy data if the field is NPK = (Input). My query stack in here :

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Satker IN ('111111', '666666');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `OR` in the `WHERE` clause as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
 WHERE Satker IN ('111111', '666666')
   and (Privasi = 'Umum' or npk = 211017)
```

Comment: The query does not work, and only ID 1 and 2 are display. It should appear ID 1, 2, and 6.

Comment: For ID = 6, Satker = 666666 and Privasi = 'Umum'. it means both the conditions are satisfied then why it is not comming in your result? I have a doubt that you are not using the exact query

Comment: I have tried with this query, and the results are as I expected. But I haven't tried as far as possible. Is my query correct, or is there anything better than this ? SELECT NPK, Satker, Privasi FROM table WHERE Satker IN ( '111111', '666666' ) AND ( Privasi = 'Umum' ) OR ( NPK = '211017' AND Privasi = 'Rahasia' )

Comment: `AND ( ( Privasi = 'Umum' ) OR ( NPK = '211017' AND Privasi = 'Rahasia' ) )` see extra parenthesis

Answer (score 0):

IMO just break it down to two queries and `UNION`.
First part for other data and sec part for input (211017):

```
select * from [table] where Satker in ('111111', '666666') and Privasi = 'Umum'
union
select * from [table] where NPK = 211017
```

`union` will take care of duplicate `npk = 211017`.

also using `or` :

```
select * from [table] 
where (Satker in ('111111', '666666') and Privasi = 'Umum')
or NPK = 211017
```

Comment: What problem does this solve that OR wouldn't?

Comment: @Strawberry just a process of my logic, `or` is better. but the problem stick do OP want every row with `npk = 211017` or the row also with `satker in ('111111', '666666')`?

Comment: The query does not work, and only ID 1 and 2 are display. It should appear ID 1, 2, and 6.